# Identify children's book from 80's

Tags: story-identification

Bit of a long shot but I'm trying to remember a book that I read as a young boy, around 1980 or so.

Primarily a picture book that featured a boy who lived on a farm, who went out at night on an adventure, and there was a combine harvester he mistook for a monster.  I also seem to remember a character as a fox.

Comment: Was there a SF/F element to the story?

Comment: Not so much sci-fi, but definitely fantasy.

Comment: If you remember what it was, or anything else about the story, it would be helpful to add to your question.

Comment: Sure, I will.  As I said, it's a long shot as my memory of it is very vague...

Comment: Can't possible be what you are looking for, but the young protagonist of Varley's *The Golden Globe* has a fearful encounter with the Daewoo-Caterpillar.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like *[The Werefox](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0020427603)* (original title *Pure Magic*), by Elizabeth Coatsworth, published in 1975.

I haven't read it myself, but it is described as a book about a boy and his friend, who is a werefox, having adventures at night (when his friend becomes a fox).  I haven't located any explicit mention of encountering a combine, but it certainly seems like it could be plausible given the story's setting on an English farm.